# View JAVA_OPTS currently set under linux

Tags: linux, jvm

Ok newbie linux question here but i cant for the life of me find the answer to it

I can set new JAVA_OPTS settings for tomcat but cannot figure out how to view the current settings for JAVA_OPTS.  The server is CentOS and jdk is OpenJDK 1.6.0_24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have XWindow, you can run jconsole, and attach to your target process. Then, you can see JAVA_OPTS in the row of "VM arguments" of the tab "VM Summary".